# PHP MySQL Insert from drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, sql-insert

Just a quick question. I am sure it is not as complicated as I think. I have a page that has 4 drop down menus. These are all populated from a database which is MySQL. Upon a submission I would like these options to be inserted into a different table. For the life of me I can no figure this out. Please if you could just let me know a bit of code that would achieve this it would be greatly appreciated. I have been attempting this for a day or so now. Thanks in advance for the help. Also note these are just snippets of code. Some might not have closing tags etc.

PHP CODE:

```
    <?php

//connecting to DB
$myServer   = "";
$myUsername = "";
$myPassword = "";
$myDatabase = "";

$myQuery1   = "SELECT DispatchUrgency.DispatchUrgencyID, DispatchUrgency.DispatchUrgencyName FROM DispatchUrgency ORDER BY DispatchUrgency.DispatchUrgencyName";
$myQuery2   = "SELECT DispatchStatus.DispatchStatusID, DispatchStatus.DispatchStatusName FROM DispatchStatus ORDER BY DispatchStatus.DispatchStatusID";
$myQuery3   = "SELECT Installer.InstallerID, CONCAT_WS(' ', PackingSlipLocation.ContactName, Installer.InstallerRegion, PackingSlipLocation.ContactPhone) as expr1 FROM PackingSlipLocation INNER JOIN Installer ON PackingSlipLocation.PackingSlipLocationID=Installer.InstallerPackingSlipLocationID";
$myQuery4   = "SELECT Location.LocationID, CONCAT_WS(' ', SystemName, id1poc, sitenamelocation, siteaddress1) as expr2 FROM Location";
$myQuery5   = "SELECT DispatchUrgency.DispatchUrgencyID FROM DispatchUrgency WHERE DispatchUrgencyName = '".$_POST['element_11']."'";

$myConnection = mysql_connect($myServer,$myUsername,$myPassword);
if (!$myConnection){
   die('Conncetion Failed:' . mysql_error()  );
}
@mysql_select_db($myDatabase) or die("Unable to select database");


$result1 = mysql_query($myQuery1) or die (mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query($myQuery2) or die (mysql_error());
$result3 = mysql_query($myQuery3) or die (mysql_error());
$result4 = mysql_query($myQuery4) or die (mysql_error());
$options = "";

if(mysql_num_rows($result1)){ 
$select1= '<select name="element_11" class="element select large" id="element_11">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
      $select1.='<option value="'.$rs['DispatchUrgencyID'].'">'.$rs['DispatchUrgencyName'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select1.='</select>'; 


if(mysql_num_rows($result2)){ 
$select2= '<select class="element select large" id="element_12" name="element_12">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
      $select2.='<option value="'.$rs['DispatchStatusID'].'">'.$rs['DispatchStatusName'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select2.='</select>';


if(mysql_num_rows($result3)){ 
$select3= '<select class="element select large" id="element_13" name="element_13">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result3)){ 
      $select3.='<option value="'.$rs['Installer.InstallerID'].'">'.$rs['expr1'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select3.='</select>';


if(mysql_num_rows($result4)){ 
$select4= '<select class="element select large" id="element_14" name="element_14">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result4)){ 
      $select4.='<option value="'.$rs['Installer.InstallerID'].'">'.$rs['expr2'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select4.='</select>';

?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
<form id="form_631187" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
        <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Dispatch Form</h2>
        </div>                      


    <ul>

        <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Dispatch ID </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_11" >
        <label class="description" for="element_11">Urgency</label>
        <div>


        <?php echo $select1; ?>

        </div> 
        </li>       
        <li id="li_12" >

        <label class="description" for="element_12">Status</label>

        <div>

        <?php echo $select2; ?>

        </div> 

        </li>       
        <li id="li_13" >

        <label class="description" for="element_13">Installers</label>

        <div>   

        <?php echo $select3; ?>

        </div> 

        </li>   
        <li id="li_14" >

        <label class="description" for="element_14">Location </label>

        <div>

        <?php echo $select4; ?>

        </div> 

        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things I noticed:

```
<form id="form_631187" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
```

has no action parameter. You need to put something like:

```
<form id="form_631187" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="form_handler.php">
```

Then you need to create form_handler.php and get the forms contents in the $_POST array. On this page that you create you need to do the update/insert to the table that holds the values in the form.

Comment: if this isn't the problem then let me know what is breaking or what errors you might be getting

Comment: Thank you. This is all done on one page so it isnt really an issue with the action. I have a text box as well with a name of "box1". If I use $_POST['box1'] the insert works beautifully. But if I try an inset from the drop down it does not insert.

Comment: try $_POST['element_11'],  $_POST['element_12'],  $_POST['element_13'], $_POST['element_14']. The $_POST goes off the name attribute in the select boxes.

Comment: Great Thanks! That is what I was doing but it wasnt working for some reason. I just started this again and again it seems to work. Thanks so much for your help.